# Photoshop CC 2015 - New layers are all white, not transparent

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm running Photoshop CC 2015 on Mac OS X 10.11.

Since upgrading to Photoshop CC 2015 (`2015.1.2 20160113.r.355`) when I create a new layer it's all white, when I select pixels and press the Delete key the pixels remain white - I'm unable to get transparent pixels. The layer is a "normal" layer, not a Background layer.

I note this happens even when <kbd>File > New > Background Contents:</kbd> is explicitly set to <kbd>Transparent</kbd>.

Under <kbd>Preferences > Transparency</kbd> I have the default settings of Medium Grid Size and Light Grid Colors.

How do I get transparent pixels back?

UPDATE: I'm having the same issue as described here: https://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/photoshop-cc-2015-checkerboard-preview-for-transparency-in-thumbnails-and-artboards-are-gone

Comment: What is the bitness your working in, or Image Mode?  I have heard of this problem before , in that case long ago it was because they were in indexed color modes , or greyscale or whatever modes it can be in that do not show/have a transparency layer.

Comment: @Psycogeek 32-bit RGB mode. I was finally able to get Photoshop CC 2014 installed and it shows the Transparency Grid fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Photoshop CC 2015 does still in-fact have the Transparency Grid - it's just disabled in "Artboard Mode" - a mode which can be enabled too easily and without realising it.

If you create a new Photoshop document in CC 2015 by <kbd>File > New > Default Photoshop Size</kbd> then you'll get a "normal" document, however if you choose anything else in the New Document dialog you'll likely get an "Artboard document".

You can get-out of an artboard document mode by opening the <kbd>Layer</kbd> menu and choosing <kbd>Ungroup Artboards</kbd> - if you're not in Artboard mode you won't see that option because it's renamed to <kbd>Ungroup Layers</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Ugh.

Apparently this is "by design". Even though Photoshop Preferences retains the Transparency Grid options page, the feature is permanently disabled in the main document view and layer thumbnails, see here: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1872120

Adobe:

> Hey guys,
>
> As I understand it, in our user testing this was the most useful behavior requested by designers. We do plan to make it more configurable in the future.
>
> Regards
>   Pete

aaaaargghhhh

To add insult to injury, the Adobe CC installer doesn't do anything when I instruct it to install Photoshop CC 2014.

**Update** I fixed the Adobe CC installation issue by deleting my CC `OOBE` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if you are in Artboard mode, there is a dropdown menu in the Properties panel called "**Artboard background color**" under which you can select "**Transparent**" rather than "White"